# React Redux - Table of select dropdowns with mutually exclusive options

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm scratching my head on this one. And i find it's also not easy to explain. I'll do my best:

I have an html table, each row has an image and, amongst other elements, also a select dropdown with a top 10 list, to rank the image.
When a user selects a ranking, the database gets updated accordingly ->
The current image top 10 ranking is saved in the image entry, and the rank of the former image to inherit the position gets updated to 'null'. (this is already working -> so if I reload the page, everything turns up fine).
What I'm unable to achieve, is for the updated images array that I receive back from the db to update the state (or the props) and therefor the selected option value of the image that formerly inherited the rank.
Here's my `ImageList` Component (the important parts):

```
class ImageList extends Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      project: [],
      description: '',
      name: '',
      values: [],
      value: '',
      positions: props.positions
    }
  }

  updatePosition = (projectId, projectName, imageId, imgName, i, e) => {

    this.props.setGridPosition(
      projectId,
      projectName,
      imageId,
      imgName,
      e.target.value
    )
  }

  getAllImages() {
    let imageList = []
    if (this.props.project.project) {
      const { project, waiting } = this.props.project

      for (let [i, img] of project.images.entries()) {
        if (!img.isDeleted) {
          let options = ['-', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
          this.props.positions[i] = img.gridPosition

          let imgSrc = `/public/${project._id}/${img.originalName}`
          imageList.push(
            <tr
              key={img._id}
              style={waiting ? { opacity: '.5' } : { opacity: '1' }}
            >
              <td>
                <img src={imgSrc} alt="" style={{ width: '60px' }} />
              </td>

                <SelectFieldGroup
                  name={`placeInGrid_${i}`}
                  onChange={this.updatePosition.bind(
                    this,
                    project._id,
                    project.name,
                    img._id,
                    img.originalName,
                    i
                  )}
                  options={options}
                  value={this.props.positions[i]}
                />
              </td>

            </tr>
          )
        }
      }
    }
    return imageList
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles['image-list']}>
        <table className={styles['image-table']}>
          <tbody>{this.getAllImages()}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  project: state.project
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { deleteImage, setGridPosition }
)(ImageList)
```

I receive the props - the project and positions (as an empty array) - from the parent Component.

I hope the issue is somehow clear. I would really appreciate any help or pointers to where I went wrong.

**Edit:**
As requested, for clarification, here are some other parts of the code:

`SelectFieldGroup.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import cx from 'classnames'
import globalStyles from './Bootstrap.module.css'
import commonStyles from './Common.module.sass'

const SelectFieldGroup = ({ name, onChange, options, value, disabled }) => {
  let optionArray = []
  for (let [index, option] of options.entries()) {
    optionArray.push(<option key={index}>{option}</option>)
  }

  return (
    <div className={globalStyles['form-group']}>
      <select
        value={value}
        className={cx(
          globalStyles['custom-select'],
          commonStyles['custom-select'],
          commonStyles['dark-input']
        )}
        name={name}
        onChange={onChange}
        disabled={disabled}
      >
        {optionArray}
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}

SelectFieldGroup.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  disabled: PropTypes.string
}

export default SelectFieldGroup
```

The relevant part of `imageActions.`:

```
export const setGridPosition = (
  projectId,
  projectName,
  imageId,
  imageName,
  position
) => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setWaiting())
  const data = {
    projectId: projectId,
    projectName: projectName,
    imageId: imageId,
    imageName: imageName,
    position: position
  }
  console.log(projectId)
  axios
    .post('/api/projects/set_grid_position', data)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      dispatch({
        type: SET_GRID_POSITION,
        payload: res.data
      })
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: {}
      })
    )
}
```

The node express api:

```
router.post(
  '/set_grid_position',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const errors = {}
    Project.findById(req.body.projectId).then(currentProject => {
      let updatedProject = currentProject
      ProjectGridPosition.findOne({ position: req.body.position }).then(
        gridPosition => {
          if (req.body.position != '-') {
            // Mark the previous position of the image as empty.
            ProjectGridPosition.findOne({ imageId: req.body.imageId })
              .then(oldPos => {
                oldPos.isTaken = false
                oldPos.save()
              })
              .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err))
            // Set the gridPosition inside the image.
            currentProject.images.forEach(img => {
              if (img._id == req.body.imageId) {
                img.gridPosition = req.body.position
              }
            })
            currentProject.save(err => {
              if (err) res.json(err)
              else {
                updatedProject = currentProject
              }
            })

            if (gridPosition) {
              if (gridPosition.projectId) {
                Project.findById(gridPosition.projectId)
                  .then(project => {
                    console.log(project.name)
                    project.images.forEach(img => {
                      if (img.gridPosition == req.body.position) {
                        console.log(img.originalName)
                        img.gridPosition = '-'
                      }
                    })
                    project.save(err => {
                      if (err) {
                        res.json(err)
                      } else {
                        if (project == currentProject) {
                          updatedProject = currentProject
                        }
                      }
                    })
                  })
                  .catch(err => res.json(err))
              }
              gridPosition.projectId = req.body.projectId
              gridPosition.projectName = req.body.projectName
              gridPosition.imageId = req.body.imageId
              gridPosition.imageName = req.body.imageName
              gridPosition.isTaken = true
              gridPosition.save()

              res.json(updatedProject)
            } else {
              const newPosFields = {
                projectId: req.body.projectId,
                projectName: req.body.projectName,
                imageId: req.body.imageId,
                imageName: req.body.imageName,
                position: req.body.position,
                isTaken: true
              }
              new ProjectGridPosition(newPosFields)
                .save()
                .then(() => {
                  currentProject.save().then(() => {
                    res.json(currentProject)
                  })
                })

                .catch(err => res.json(err))
            }
          } else {
            currentProject.images.forEach(img => {
              if (img._id == req.body.imageId) {
                img.gridPosition = req.body.position
              }
            })
            currentProject.save(err => {
              if (err) res.json(err)
              ProjectGridPosition.findOne({ imageId: req.body.imageId }).then(
                newPos => {
                  newPos.isTaken = false
                  newPos.save().then(() => {
                    currentProject.save().then(() => {
                      res.json(currentProject)
                    })
                  })
                }
              )
            })
          }
        }
      )
    })
  }
)
```

And finally, the relevant part of `projectReducer.js`:

```
import {
  // ...
  SET_GRID_POSITION
} from '../actions/types'

const initialState = {
  project: null,
  projects: null,
  loading: false,
  waiting: false
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    // ....

    case SET_GRID_POSITION:
      return {
        ...state,
        project: action.payload,
        waiting: false
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: It may be helpful to see the definition of `SelectFieldGroup`. Is that a custom component or one from another library?

Comment: can you add your reducer code where you are saving your update images array and also the `setGridPosition` action code in order to have a better view at your state management.

Comment: @Tex Thanks, I edited the question!

Comment: @PranayTripathi Thanks, I edited the question!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the additional code. The challenge now is that there's quite a lot of code to try to digest all at once. I think the source of your problem, though, is in `getAllImages`, specifically here: `this.props.positions[i] = img.gridPosition`. One should never mutate `props` directly. Rather, one should update the state (either component state via `setState` or Redux*) and let React (and potentially Redux) take care of updating the component when the positions change.

* If I had to choose between component state and Redux, I'd definitely choose Redux here.

Comment: Side note: While the code you've shared is clean and nicely formatted, it's also verbose and, at times, unnecessarily complicated. The route has 11 `if` statements and 13 levels of nesting - both warning flags for me. The route also relies on confusing object mutation and has repetitive and even unnecessary code. Verbose `for` loops with `push` statements can be replaced with less verbose `map` operations. The code would benefit from a thorough review. The same functionality can be written in a much simpler, less verbose and easy-to-digest fashion, making it easier for outsiders to understand.

Comment: @Tex thank you! I gave it a good thought and restructured some of the code. I actually completely got rid of the ProjectGridPosition model and rewrote the route completely. Now I just save the ranks inside the images and delete them if they get overwritten. It's much cleaner now and It actually works. So though I'm not really sure what exactly caused the problem - it was definitely a case of overcomplicating things. So thank you for the input! Since this is my first question I'm not really sure how to procede in this case. It's not really answered, but it is solved. Should I just delete it?

Comment: Glad you got it working! I actually don't know what the recommended course of action is in this case. I guess it doesn't hurt to leave the question. You could also post your own answer (something like your most recent comment) and accept the answer so people know you're not still looking for assistance.

Comment: @Tex Thanks, I wrote it as an answer and will accept it as soon as I'm allowed to (in 4 hours.) Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to make it work by restructuring and getting rid of the ProjectGridPosition model completely. Doing so makes the whole process a lot simpler. I then completely rewrote the route:

```
router.post(
  '/set_grid_position',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  async (req, res) => {
    let project = await getProjectById(req.body.projectId)
    const query = {
      'images.gridPosition': req.body.position
    }
    let formerRankProject = await getProjectByQuery(query)

    project = await updateRank(project, req.body.imageId, req.body.position)

    if (formerRankProject !== null) {
      formerRankProject = await UpdateIfDifferentProject(
        formerRankProject,
        project._id,
        req.body
      )
      formerRankProject.save()
    }

    project
      .save()
      .then(project => res.json(project))
      .catch(err => res.json(err))
  }
)
```

Now it's working. I don't exactly know what the problem was, but as @Tex pointed out in the comments, I had a LOT of levels of nesting - so something probably was bound to go wrong.

I will mark this as the correct answer - even though it's more of a work around - so people know, I'm not still looking for help.